# Elegant way to get per month Stats from DB (without dynamic SQL)?

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

Consider getting the number of orders per month. I currently have this:

```
select
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-01-01' and o.created_at < '2017-02-01') as "Jan",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-02-01' and o.created_at < '2017-03-01') as "Feb",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-03-01' and o.created_at < '2017-04-01') as "Mar",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-04-01' and o.created_at < '2017-05-01') as "Apr",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-05-01' and o.created_at < '2017-06-01') as "May",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-06-01' and o.created_at < '2017-07-01') as "Jun",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-07-01' and o.created_at < '2017-08-01') as "Jul",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-08-01' and o.created_at < '2017-09-01') as "Aug",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-09-01' and o.created_at < '2017-10-01') as "Sep",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-10-01' and o.created_at < '2017-11-01') as "Oct",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-11-01' and o.created_at < '2017-12-01') as "Nov",
  (select count(*) from orders o where o.created_at >= '2017-12-01' and o.created_at < '2018-01-01') as "Dec"
```

Is there a more dynamic/scalable way of doing this without resorting to dynamic SQL?

EDITS:

1. I would accept an answer for SQL Server or Postgres. I regularly run queries like this on both.
2. At a minimum output should match the query given. But a vertical output would be even better.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE] in the shape of a line of "create table ..." and some lines of "insert ...".

Comment: Please show the desired output for your sample input (from previous comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying DBMS, but if you were in SQL Server, you could do something like:

```
SELECT [1] as Jan,[2] as Feb,[3] as Mar,[4] as Apr,[5] as May,[6] as Jun,
[7] as Jul,[8] as Aug,[9] as Sep,[10] as Oct,[11] as Nov,[12] as Dec
FROM (
         SELECT MONTH(o.created_at) as pivotmonth
         FROM orders o
         WHERE YEAR(o.created_at) = 2017
) xt
PIVOT (
    COUNT(xt.pivotmonth) FOR xt.pivotmonth IN (
    [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) as pivottable
```

This way you get 1 column per month.

Comment: Is PIVOT unique to SQL Server? I have not come across it before.

Comment: I think Oracle also has it. My guess is that others like Postgresql or MySql should have similar things, maybe with different names. I guess google could help you with those others, example: http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function